# How to generate Api key for my app

Tags: php, api

I want to generate api key. There are some ways to generate random string. But I am afraid of duplicate random string generation. For example: if I generate 3 random string and as :

```
absd322e332
fsdafa232da
absd322e332
```

Here first one and last one is equal. But I have to be over sure that there is no duplicate random string. How can I achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Create a GUID, that's almost certain to be unique

Comment: I am using PHP @jason

Comment: You can use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PHP, try this to create a GUID (globally unique id):

http://guid.us/GUID/PHP